# Trigger IF ( UPDATE (STATUS) IN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have an UPDATE trigger on the column STATUS. This column takes int. Instead of firing on every change, I want it to fire only when STATUS changes to 3, 4 or 6.

How can I achieve this? I'm guessing I have to extend this rule?

```
IF ( UPDATE (STATUS) )
```

```
USE [TEST]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[PROJECT_StatusUpdate]    Script Date: 27-9-2023 16:47:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PROJECT_StatusUpdate] ON [dbo].[PROJECT]
AFTER UPDATE
AS

IF ( UPDATE (STATUS) )

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT [IT].[dbo].[ProjectStatusLog]
  (ProjectNO, OldStatus, NewStatus, DateChanged)
SELECT
  d.PROJECTNO,
  d.STATUS,
  i.STATUS,
  GETDATE()
FROM inserted i
FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.OBJECTID = i.OBJECTID
END;
```

Comment: you can check the value from the deleted table with the value from the inserted table, that will tell you if the value has changed, and into what it changed. Just put that into a where clause of your select query, than you even won't need the update statement anymore

Comment: But then it fires on every row change, not just the column STATUS?
Do you have an example? My knowledge of SQL is limited to 'copy paste edit'. ;-)

Comment: You can't avoid it firing on every update that's how triggers work. if you check the Microsoft documentation you can find loads of examples of using deleted and inserted.

Comment: If (SELECT [value in column X] FROM INSERTED) IN ('values', 'here')
?

Comment: Your trigger will already fire on every update, that is how it works. It is up to you to write you select query so it will only use those rows you want. There are plenty of examples on how to use deleted and inserted in the documentation and on google

Comment: `where i.status <> d.status` would tell you that the status has changed for example, you can also check what the new status has become `and i.Status in (3, 4, 6)` and many more stuff you can do

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `FULL JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` is fine. Place the required checking condition in the `WHERE` clause

```
  IF ( UPDATE (STATUS) )
  BEGIN
      INSERT [IT].[dbo].[ProjectStatusLog] 
             (ProjectNO, OldStatus, NewStatus, DateChanged)
      SELECT ProjectNO   = d.PROJECTNO,
             OldStatus   = d.STATUS,
             NewStatus   = i.STATUS,
             DateChanged = GETDATE()
      FROM   inserted i 
             INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.ProjectNO = i.ProjectNO
      WHERE  i.STATUS <> d.STATUS     -- when there is a change in STATUS value
      AND    i.STATUS IN (3, 4, 6);   -- and new value is 3, 4 or 6
  END;
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
How would i change this code if i want to check if code changes from x to y?

Comment: `and (d.Status = '1' and i.Status = '2')` will tell you that the status changed from 1 to 2

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help. Got it working.

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT [IT].[dbo].[ProjectStatusLog] 
             (ProjectNO, OldStatus, NewStatus, DateChanged)
      SELECT ProjectNO   = d.PROJECTNO,
             OldStatus   = d.STATUS,
             NewStatus   = i.STATUS,
             DateChanged = GETDATE()
      FROM   inserted i 
             INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.OBJECTID = i.OBJECTID
      WHERE  i.STATUS <> d.STATUS     -- when there is a change in STATUS value
      AND    ((i.STATUS NOT IN (4, 6)) AND (d.STATUS IN (4, 6)));   -- and new value is not 4, 6, old value is 4, 6 (annulering, teruggestuurd)
END;
```